# Initializer used when loading nodes from SKS file

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, swift3

I am creating a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` e.g. `Player` and label a `SKSpriteNode` in my *.sks file with the custom class `Player`. In the *.swift I am loading the node using: `self.childNode(withName: "myNodesName")`. Well, this works fine, but I also want to modify the constructor used for this procedure.

Which constructor  of `SKSpriteNode` is used if I access a `SKSpriteNode` in my *.swift file from its *.sks using

```
self.childNode(withName: "myNodesName") as? Player
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What constructor gets called?

When a node is created from an sks file, SpriteKit does use this initializer

```
init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

### How can you implement that into Player?

You have a Player class. You can implement the constructor this way

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: What instance does the call?

Comment: It's called by some kind of parser (I believe) with the job of converting the SKS file into an SKScene.

Comment: So probably no way of changing it?

Comment: @cocoseis: What do you need to do?

Comment: I want the Player to know its sibling (node) at the time of its init.

Comment: @cocoseis: You can't at `init` time. During `initialisation` the sprite is not yet into the scene graph. The right place for this is inside the method `didMoveToView` of your `GameScene` class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116020/discussion-between-appzyourlife-and-cocoseis).